# C# printing path of folders and files to console

Tags: c#

So I've been working on a new programm right now and I'm stuck at one function and I don't know how to solve this problem.

So I'm trying to make a button which searches and prints paths of files and folders which have a specific name. After I tried some functions and they all failed, I found this and it should work but it just doesn't print anything.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Program Files", "NameOfFileOrFolder",
            SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
        }
```

Btw. the console does not even open itself...

Comment: You say you have a "button" - what kind of app is this?

Comment: do a google search on `C# How do I show a console output/window in a forms application` and please clarify if this is a `Winforms app or Console app` and when you show code please show all relevant code for example what is `NameOffFileOrFolder` and how is it declared.. also create the application in a Console app and read up on what `Console.Read()` does in regards to pausing the console output so that you can see it.. if this is a winforms app then use a RichTextBox and use `Environment.NewLine` when you want to append new text etc..

Comment: Winform app. And NameOffFileOrFolder is the name of the files or folder which should be searched.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx
Also you need administrator's privilege for using current path.

Comment: Why would he need administrator privileges? Most folders still let you read their contents even if you cannot modify them without admin privileges.

Comment: Sure, but some folders have other permissions.

Comment: You are correct, but those are very few and usually only system folders. They're harldy found in Program Files. -- I'd say you should _advice him to run with administrator privileges_ in those cases, rather than saying _"you need it for the current path"_ as that can be very misleading.